# How to convert .ppk key to OpenSSH key under Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I know that is possible to convert .ppk under puttygen in Windows, but how to do that on Linux? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 367, accepted):

Do it with Putty.

- **Linux:** with your package manager, install PuTTY (or the more minimal PuTTY-tools):

- Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install putty-tools`
- Debian-like: `apt-get install putty-tools`
- RPM based: `dnf install putty` or `yum install putty`
- Gentoo: `emerge putty`
- Archlinux: `sudo pacman -S putty`
- etc.

- **OS X:** Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then run `brew install putty`

Place your keys in some directory, e.g. your home folder.
Now convert the PPK keys to SSH keypairs:cache search

To generate the **private** key:

```
cd ~
puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O private-openssh -o id_dsa
```

and to generate the **public** key:

```
puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O public-openssh -o id_dsa.pub
```

Move these keys to `~/.ssh` and make sure the permissions are set to private for your private key:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
mv -i ~/id_dsa* ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
chmod 666 ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

If you have already tried to perform a '**git clone**' operation you might need to do this also

```
chmod 666 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: hi i already have a .pub then it is need to  create public key again

Comment: If you came here looking for how to do it in windows, run "puttygen yourkey.ppk", and then under the Conversions menu choose "Export OpenSSH key" to get the private key.

Comment: the solution from @jous is much nicer since you don't need the private key to convert a public key + you don't need to install putty

Comment: I had to add this key to my `./ssh/config` file 
`Host mysite.com
    Hostname mysite.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes`

Comment: Some elliptic curve formats (ECDS etc) are only available in the beta putty tools yet.

Comment: Never, ever set a Linux/Unix file to permissions "666" unless you have a very good reason. Both examples here should be 644 - others should be allowed to read, but *never* allowed to write to SSH related files.

Answer (score 49):

```
ssh-keygen -i -f id_dsa_1024_a.pub > id_dsa_1024_a_openssh.pub
```

- `-i` flag is import from other than openssh format
- `-f` flag means read from input file

Source: a [blogpost](http://burnz.wordpress.com/2007/12/14/ssh-convert-openssh-to-ssh2-and-vise-versa/) at burnz.wordpress.com

Comment: .ppk files are the full key pairs, I don't think the command above or the blog post apply to that.

Comment: I think I meant that it works if you use puttygen's "Save public key" button. ssh-keygen do not understand true .ppk files because they lack those '---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----' markers. You can  find the public key in the .ppk file between lines "Public-Lines:.." and "Private-Lines:.." though.

Comment: This worked for me with a public-key file - puttygen seems to require a private key.  it's seems that all it did was rearrange the base-64 part into a single line

Comment: This does not seem to cover private keys, which is why I would want to do the conversion, I already have a public key saved somewhere...

Comment: Yeah, the ppk files I've seen have had the appropriate markers, and this has worked _just fine_.

Answer (score 13):

**Get the private key:**

open the .ppk file in puttygen:

```
puttygen ~/.ssh/id_dsa.ppk
```

export as openssh:

Conversions → Export OpenSSH key

**Get the public key:**

open like before the **private key** with puttygen, the public key is under
*public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file*

Answer (score 9):

I prepared a Docker container to make life simpler:

```
docker run --rm \
           --volume=/path/to/file.ppk:/tmp/id_dsa.ppk \
           --volume=/path/to/output:/tmp/out/ \
           czerasz/putty-tools
```

Where:

- `/path/to/file.ppk` - local path to your ppk file
- `/path/to/output` - local path to where the private and public key should be placed

Comment: great. thx for the image! however meanwhile its `--volume=/path/to/file.ppk:/tmp/id.ppk` and not `id_dsa.ppk`

Comment: You may like to add `--network none`

Comment: I get `puttygen: error loading '/tmp/id.ppk': PuTTY key format too new`

Comment: Thanks! I've forked a new image `crowne/putty-tools` which solves the `PuTTY key format too new` error