# using puttygen generated public keys in unix environment?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert .ppk key to OpenSSH key *under Linux*?](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux)

(unix, here: ubuntu 10.4)

I know how to create ssh key pairs in unix (ssh-keygen) and how to do it in windows (puttygen). the missing part in my case would be how to use a keypair, generated in windows (puttygen), in a unix shell.

where do I need to put the public key, in this particular case, to use it as an ssh-key in git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I didn't make myself quite clear but found the solution:

1. start puttygen
2. load private key
3. Menu Conversions|Export OpenSSH key
4. Save somewhere, Open, Copy content to clipboard, paste on linux into file: $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa
5. (optionally) copy content of text area "Public Key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file", paste on linux into file: $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub

you can now use this SSH key from a shell to login into remote systems.

side note: to seamlessly use git from windows putty in a linux shell to connect to git set these options in putty session:

[image]

(and you must put the public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, sure..)

Comment: Which is kind of what grawity and I wrote ;)

Comment: you talked only about logging INTO a machine and grawity missed the important part of the question: where to put the files. thanks anyway..

Comment: (The answer being "absolutely anywhere".)

Answer (score 6):

The Puttygen window contains a text area with the public key in the format expected by SSH.

Copy it, and add it to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server on its own separate line. Make sure the file and the directory are not readable/writeable by group and others, i.e. run `chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Then the server will accept your login using the private key for authentication.

Comment: Definitely use this if connecting from Windows to Unix.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on which key you need...

### Private key – to log in *from* a Unix system into another Unix

You must first convert the key, using PuTTYgen, from PuTTY format to one OpenSSH can use.

- In the Windows version of PuTTYgen, use the *Conversions → Export OpenSSH key* menu item;
- in the Linux version, `puttygen mykey.ppk -O private-openssh -o mykey`.

### Only public key – for logging in from Windows *to* Unix

See Daniel's answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I didn't make myself quite clear but found the solution:

 1. start puttygen
 2. load private key
 3. Menu Conversions|Export OpenSSH key
 4. Save somewhere, Open, Copy content to clipboard, paste on linux into file: $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa
 5. copy content of text area "Public Key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file", paste on linux into file: $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub

Comment: you can now use this SSH key from a linux shell to login into remote systems.

side note: to seamlessly use git from windows putty in a linux shell to connect to git set these options in putty session: http://i.imgur.com/lh5LT.png (and you must put the public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the linux system and in git under public keys) (will put this as self answer, when I'm allowed, karma-wise)

Comment: @perler: Users are [*always* allowed](http://superuser.com/privileges/new-user) to answer questions, including their own. Also, the `.pub` file is optional.

Comment: no you can't for 8 hours with karma below 100, big letters told me ;)