# How to convert .ppk key with passphrase to OpenSSH key in batch?

Tags: linux, ssh, batch, openssh

My question is related to that one [How to convert .ppk key to OpenSSH key under Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/232362/1785126) But in the case when the .ppk can have an associated passphrase.

According to [the man page of puttygen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/puttygen) “there's currently no way to supply passphrases in batch mode, ...”

Is there a way to convert a .ppk with a passphrase to OpenSSH key in non-interactive mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual page you're reading is outdated. Options to supply old and new passphrases were added to PuTTYgen in 2016, in version 0.68.

```
  --old-passphrase file
        specify file containing old key passphrase
  --new-passphrase file
        specify file containing new key passphrase
```

Do not use linux.die.net in 2023. It's completely unmaintained now – sometimes the manual pages are a few years old, sometimes *twenty* years old. Use the manual page archives maintained by Linux distributions, e.g. https://man.archlinux.org/ or https://manpages.debian.org/ instead.

(Of course, the manual pages installed *on your system* would be the most up-to-date. There are graphical programs to read them, e.g. GNOME's `yelp`. It's also possible to render manual pages into HTML using `man -Thtml puttygen > /tmp/foo.html` if you find reading them in terminal inconvenient.)

---

Alternative: With anything that takes line-based input from stdin or tty, you can also use `expect` to feed input "interactively". That is, write an Expect script that runs puttygen in *non*-batch mode and waits for the appropriate prompt.

For example, if you were forced to use an old version of puttygen that *didn't* have the `--old-passphrase` option, something like this would be able to convert a single file (the script uses Tcl syntax with a few Expect-specific commands added):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set infile [lindex $argv 0]
set passphrase [lindex $argv 1]
set outfile [string map {.ppk .key} $infile]
spawn puttygen <some options>
expect "Password:" { send $passphrase }
expect "some other prompt:" { send "something else" }
```